# Configuring Windows Client for NFS

Tags: windows-10, nfs

this question is about configuring **Windows 10** Client for NFS. There are two parts to it, 1) map the export (drive), 2) set IM 
Let's have NFS export (/media/NFS_share 192.168.0.*(rw,async)) already present and running properly, verified from another *nix boxes sharing same network range. Now, for mounting the export on Windows box we need Services for NFS installed and simply mount:

```
mount.exe 192.168.0.2:/media/NFS_share *
```

Command unfortunately results in:

```
Network Error - 53
Type 'NET HELPMSG 53' for more information.
```

Which is clearly incorrect:

```
PS C:\Users> showmount -e 192.168.0.2
Exports list on 192.168.0.2:
/media/NFS_share                   192.168.0.*
```

So, 1) what is the issue with the mounting? 'Path not found' is somehow misleading message.

Next step would be setting identity mapping. While there are multiple ways, I chose local passwd and group files. But IdentityMapping log in ServicesForNFS-Client event log do not mention files at all, insisting on failed AD connection like there are no passwd/group files present in %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc.
 2) Are local files ment for Server only? Should AnonymousUid/Gid registry setting be used for client instead?

/edit: It would be worth of mentioning that opening \\192.168.0.2 in Windows explorer shows the share as \media\NFS_share but clicking it results in 'access denied' error, which seems to be more appropriate than err 53.